# iOS got a very long repeating Settings list

Tags: iphone, ios

The application list in `Settings` is becoming very long. I can hardly scroll to the bottom. The list might have repeated for more than 40 times.

I don't know how this happened (suddenly or one by one).

I think this is a bug, but I don't know how to reproduce.

The phone is an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.3.

As the picture, this app list repeats for about 40 times. I only installed about 20 apps, but it takes me quite a while to scroll to the bottom.

This doesn't affect the usage anyway, just curious.

[image: App List]

Comment: Same for any iPhone weirdness. Restart. If no joy, in iTunes, Sync; Backup; Restore.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I'm confused what's repeating. The above advice is sound.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know restart may solve the problem. I just want to know if anyone know how to reproduce it, then we can give Apple a feedback.

Answer (score -3):

Think app list may repeat due to multiple syncing. A restart may sort this.